# How to style .shown() div button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/LqbGz/2/), edited to use two divs instead of two tables (`#kellypockets` and `#birkinpockets`), I'm trying to style the button whose content is currently being displayed.

I've written the following script, but it doesn't seem to work (obviously, I'm new at this):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#kellypockets").css('display') === 'block') {
        $('#button2').addClass("pockets-button-active");
    }
    if ($("#birkinpockets").css('display') === 'block') {
        $('#button1').addClass("pockets-button-active");
    }
});
```

```css
.pockets-button-active {
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: em(14px);
    color: #373737;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 3px;
    border-color: #f5591b;
    @include at-query($max, $small) {
        font-size: em(12px);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1" class="pockets-button" type="button">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1079/2758/files/birkin-181x178-X2.png?3337508748521283727" width="89px" alt="Hermes Birkin icon" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; vertical-align: middle;" /> Hermes Birkin
</button>
<button id="button2" class="pockets-button" type="button">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1079/2758/files/kelly-181x178-X2.png?3337508748521283727" width="89px" alt="Hermes Birkin icon" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" /> Hermes Kelly
</button>
<div id="kellypockets" class="grid pockets">Bla</div>
<div id="birkinpockets" class="grid pockets">Bla</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should always start by checking for errors in your [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). In this case, for instance, you're missing `')` after both instances of `'block`.

Comment: can you also show us your `html`?

Comment: Thank you, I've added `'` only because `')` wasn't working. Any more pointers? :)

Comment: You're also missing leading `(` (and still the closing `)` after both `if`s.

Comment: Code snippets are generally used to show a working model, otherwise use the code block tag.

Comment: @HunterTurner When the answer to a question is a typo, please don't fix that typo in an edit.

Comment: instead of `.css('display') === 'block'` you can use `.is(':visible')`

Comment: @Diane Can you please add the HTML you are using to the question as well? We know you replaced the tables with divs, but what about the stuff inside the tables?

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes now added to the question

Comment: @TylerH it should be added to the original post now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LqbGz/7/ check this @Diane

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes amazing! That's almost it. The only problem with the code you provided is that it doesn't display either of the divs by default. When the page first loads, I'd like to have #birkinpockets displayed and #button1 in its active class. Can you help?

Comment: you will need to add `css` http://jsfiddle.net/LqbGz/8/

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes am confused, sorry. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/un6ce7cr/ - this is where I am right now. Everything works except the second button doesn't take the active class. Do you know why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/un6ce7cr/1/ @Diane i have removed css

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes amazing, with a bit of tweaking it worked! thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You've got syntax errors, missing `(` and `)` in the if statements

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

       if ($("#kellypockets").css('display') === 'block') {
          $('#button2').addClass("pockets-button-active");
       }

       if ($("#birkinpockets").css('display') === 'block') {
          $('#button1').addClass("pockets-button-active");
       } 

     });

</script>
```

Comment: Don't use code snippets if you h ave nothing to show, please simply use the code formatting.

Comment: Sorry about that @JonH and thanks for letting me know. Any clue on how to further solve the problem?